# How do I send mass emails yet make them more personnly one recipient's email show up in the To: form?

Tags: email, privacy, privacy-protection

I would like send an email to many users.  I would only like each recipient to see only their own email address in the To: form of the email.  Not the list of 50 recipients that the email was actually sent to.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the list in the BCC field if you are using a "fat" clieet like Outlook.

Comment: Exactly. See also; http://email.about.com/od/emailnetiquette/a/cc_and_bcc.htm (differences between To, CC, and BCC explained).

Comment: If I use BCC: what is displayed in the To: form? Nothing?

Comment: The receipient name will be displayed if you use BCC

Comment: A common practice also is to put your own email address in the to field, then BCC all the intended recipients.

Comment: BBlake Good tip!